# After recent change in Raspbian, how to change Raspberry 3 B+ Wifi country or enable 5 Ghz?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I am trying to enable 5 Ghz on my Pi because the speed I am getting is 10 Mbps or less while my old HTC M7 on 5Ghz is able to get 80 Mbps but raspbian is not letting me change the country to enable 5 Ghz, below are the things I tried.

1. Changing WiFi location from raspbian preferences.
2. Changing WiFi Location using command *sudo iw reg set US* [Results in GUI saying wifi country not set]
3. Changing country in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
4. systemctl disable wifi-country.service

*$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no*

I found below in Raspbian change log:
WiFi is disabled until wireless regulatory domain is set (Pi 3 B+ only)
    - The domain can be done through 'Raspberry Pi Configuration' (rc_gui),
      'raspi-config' or by setting 'country=' to an appropriate ISO 3166
      alpha2 country code in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.
  * Default wireless regulatory domain is now unset

I found following behavior:
If I connect to access point which has country set to US then US is set in raspbian too (confirmed using *sudo iw reg get* and I could see 5 Ghz access point). If I connect it to my other router (which I don't have access to see or change config) it goes back to a neighbouring country.

So is there anyway left I could change the country or I have to change the distro to solve this problem.

Comment: Either 1 or 3 will work.  You SHOULD NOT use `iw` to set configuration. If it isn't working list what YOU DID.

Comment: `a neighbouring country` - which one?